# remove / reset inherited css from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, embedded-script

I know this question was asked before, but before marking it as a duplicate, I want to tell you that my situation is a little different from what I found on the internet.

I'm building and embedded script that people can put it on their sites. This script creates a div with a certain width/height and some information in it.

My problem is that some websites declare styles for div that are inherited by my div as well.

for example:

```
div{
    background-color:red;
}
```

so if I don't set any background color to my div, it will show red even if I don't want that.

The only solutions I come along is to overwrite as many css proprieties, this way my div will show exactly as I want.
The problem with this solution is that there are too many css proprieties to overwrite and I want my script to be as light as it can be.

So my question is if you know another solution to my problem.
It can be in css/javascript /jQuery.

Thanks

Comment: How about giving your div a class, and then supplying a corresponding style-sheet that your div's users can either include or concatenate onto the end of their existing style-sheet. That way you can supply all of the default formatting that you want, but with the added advantage for your users that they can modifiy the defaults if desired. I know that's no lighter than you putting the styles you want inline, but it's more flexible and therefore of greater benefit to your users. I've seen jQuery plugins that work that way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Resetting" styles for a specific element isn't possible, you'll have to overwrite all styles you don't want/need. If you do this with CSS directly or using JQuery to apply the styles (depends on what's easier for you, but I wouldn't recommend using [JavaScript/JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for this, as it's completely unnecessary).

If your div is some kind of "widget" that can be included into other sites, you could try to wrap it into an [iframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames). This will "reset" the styles, because its content is another document, but maybe this affects how your widget works (or maybe breaks it completely) so this might not be possible in your case.

Comment: I was thinking about iframe, but like you said it will lead me to other problems much major than this.

Comment: However I think organizing your styles is a always a better solution but I understand sometime you have to apply a quick fix. So I think from my horrible point of view that this question is better for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Comment: UPDATE for 2019: "resetting" styles for a specific element isn't possible, Yes it is possible `all: unset` works for me.

Answer (score 12):

Only set the relevant / important CSS properties.

Example (only change the attributes which may cause your div to look completely different):

```
background: #FFF;
border: none;
color: #000;
display: block;
font: initial;
height: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-transform: none;
visibility: visible;
width: auto;
word-spacing: normal;
z-index: auto;
```

Choose a very specific selector, such as `div#donttouchme`, `<div id="donttouchme"></div>`. Additionally, you can add `!important before every semicolon in the declaration. Your customers are deliberately trying to mess up your lay-out when this option fails.

Answer (score 8):

You could try overwriting the CSS and use auto

I don't think this will work with color specifically, but I ran into an issue where i had a parent property such as

```
.parent {
   left: 0px;
}
```

and then I was able to just define my child with something like

```
.child {
   left: auto;
}
```

and it effectively "reset" the property.

Comment: More specifically set property to its default value (`auto` isn't available on everything, such as colors).  It's not unsetting the inherited value, just explicitly returning it to its default.

Answer (score 5):

Technically what you are looking for is the [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) value in combination with the shorthand property [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all):

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, and like the initial keyword in the second case. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.

```css
.customClass {
  /* specific attribute */
  color: unset; 
}

.otherClass{
  /* unset all attributes */
  all: unset; 
  /* then set own attributes */
  color: red;
}
```

You can use the [initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) value as well, this will default to the initial browser value.

```
.otherClass{
  /* unset all attributes */
  all: initial; 
  /* then set own attributes */
  color: red;
}
```

**As an alternative:**
If possible it is probably good practice to encapsulate the class or id in a kind of namespace:

```css
.namespace .customClass{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="namespace">
  <div class="customClass"></div>
</div>
```

because of the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector this will only influence your own classes

It is easier to accomplish this in "preprocessor scripting languages" like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3) with nesting capabilities:

```sass
.namespace{
  .customClass{
    color: red
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SanBen . I wish I had this option back in 2011, but it's good to know

Comment: I appreciate that this question is quite old, but this should now be the accepted/upvoted answer. In summary: User the "unset" or "initial" keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Create a plain `div` without any style or content outside of the red `div`. Now you can use a loop over all styles of the plain `div` and assign then to your inner `div` to reset all styles.

Of course this doesn't work if someone assigns styles to all `div`s (i.e. without using a class. CSS would be `div { ... }`).

The usual solution for problems like this is to give your `div` a distinct class. That way, web designers of the sites can adjust the styling of your `div` to fit into the rest of the design.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are attributes like classes and ids you can remove them by javascript/jQuery class modifiers.

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "";
```

There is no way to remove specific tag CSS other than overriding them (or using another element).

Answer (score 0):

you may use this below option.

```
<style>
  div:not(.no_common_style){
      background-color:red;
  }
</style>
```

now , if their any place where you do not want to apply default style you can use 'no_common_style' class as class.
ex:

```
<div class="no_common_style">
  It will not display in red
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to use a div that inherits from no class but yours. As mentioned in the previous reply you cannot completely reset a div inheritance. However, what worked for me with that issue was to use another element - one that is not frequent and certainly not used in the current html page. A good example, is to use  instead of  then customize it to look just like your ideal  would.

```
area { background-color : red; }
```

Answer (score -1):

One simple approach would be to use the `!important` modifier in css, but this can be overridden in the same way from users.

Maybe a solution can be achieved with jquery by traversing the entire DOM to find your (re)defined classes and removing / forcing css styles.