# How to remove CSS properties if applied in css tag based

Tags: html, css

This is very simple questions i know how to do it but i want to do it with some better way.I tried to find solutions online but couldn't find it.

Here is my css

```
a:link
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:15px;
  font-family:'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}

a:visited
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2a9dc0;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}

a:active
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2a9dc0;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}

a:hover
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2a9dc0;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

Now i have put an anchor tag but i don't want all these properties to apply to it so what i did is apply a class name `no_a` and made all css properties none  this is the way i  did is there any other way?

```
<a class="no_a" href="#">
    <article class="home_sml_box_red">
        <section class="home_small_boxtext">
            explore
        </section>

        <section class="home_small_boximage">
            <img src="image/explore_icon.png">
        </section>

        <section class="home_small_lowtext">
            Learn More
        </section>
    </article>
</a>
```

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398330/1401094)

Comment: And what is the `php` tag for..?

Comment: @Patsy Issa Link makes exact sense. I am also using common css for two different module and overwriting whenever necessary. I haven't made a new css as it is not impacting big time.

Comment: see @suhail solution that makes a proper justification how to overwrite...

Answer (score 2):

best way is

on defining css put some class in front (or `id` if only one time your are using the div). for eg:

```
.container a {
              text-decoration: none;
               color:#fff;
               font-size:15px;
                font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; sans-serif;sans-serif;
               text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
                     }
```

now you can use this in a `<div class ="container"><a href="#">sdfadsf</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`:not()` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot).

```
a:not(.no_a) {
     /* style rules for all anchors without class of no_a */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, if you don't want these properties to apply to all `<a>` tags is to not blanket apply the CSS to all `<a>` tags.  Instead, create a class that these attributes apply to, and then assign that class to the `<a>` tags that you want to have those attributes.

Comment: Maybe, but it's the correct way. If you don't want attributes applying to all `<a>` tags, don't apply them to all `<a>` tags.

Comment: The `:not` selector is supported in all major browsers including IE9+.  Or so the tubes tell me.