# How to display button as a link in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-touchkit

I am new to vaadin. I have one button it should look like a link. I have created button like,

```
Button title = new Button(item.getSubmissionTitle());
```

> title.setStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK);

I also tried using

> title.setStyleName("link);

but still I am getting look and feel of button. Is there any way to change the button using css Or any alternative ways by wich the button should appear as a link.

**EDIT**

I just found out The button is getting css from Table. And overriding the button style.
For table, it has written

> table.setDebugId("submissionsTable_id");

css for button in table is:

```
#submissionsTable_id .v-table-cell-wrapper .v-button-caption{white-space:normal !important;text-decoration:none;}

#submissionsTable_id .submission-content{width:350px;}

#submissionsTable_id .v-table-cell-wrapper .v-button-caption:hover
{
    background:#3F1A7D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#submissionsTable_id .v-button-caption:hover
{
    background:#3F1A7D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Now, How can i exclude my Link button to override the table's style or how can I add new style to button which should not inherit the style of the table.

Comment: Have you tried with addStyleName(BaseTheme.BUTTON_LINK) instead of setStyleName(...). (In non-touch it works that way) Do you have customized the theme or using plain base theme?

Comment: @AndréSchild Thanks for your reply. I have updated the Question can you share your thoughts on it. :)

Answer (score 8):

A future reference for anyone else with this issue. According to the Book of Vaadin online:
https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.button.html#figure.component.button.basic

> Some built-in themes contain a small style, which you can enable by adding Reindeer.BUTTON_SMALL, etc. The BaseTheme also has a BUTTON_LINK style, which makes the button look like a hyperlink.

If you are using the Reindeer theme the code would be:

```
title.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently resetting styles for a particular element is not possible, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398279/remove-reset-inherited-css-from-an-element) post. You have to selectively overwrite the css properties for that element in order to simulate the aspect of a link.

If it's any help, the following is some CSS I scrounged up that simulates to some degree the look and behaviour of a link:

```
a:link {
color: #0000FF;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration:underline;
}    

a:visited {
color: #800080;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration:underline;
}

a:hover {
color: #0000FF;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}   

a:active {
color: #FF0000;
background-color:#FFF;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Note that the default look and behavior of a vanilla link depends on the browser its viewed in.

Answer (score -1):

No need to play with the `Button`; there is a `Link` component for this.

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

    HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();

    Link link = new Link("Go to stackoverflow.com",
            new ExternalResource("https://stackoverflow.com/"));

    layout.setMargin(true);

    layout.addComponents(link);
    setContent(layout);
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not true - buttons and links behave in fundamentally different ways and are not interchangeable elements.