# Find and remove style attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the style attribute from a singular tr tag in a table when the corresponding tag is clicked. Have been trying some code but cannot find the solution.

here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q2nb08t6/12/
jQuery:

```
$(".tr_table").click(function(){

$(".tg_table").removeAttr('style');
//$(".tg_table").parent().find("tg_table").removeAttr('style');    
//$(".tg_table").parent().removeAttr('style');
//$(".tg_table").each().removeAttr('style');
});
```

Comment: the style is on the table node, not on the tr node.

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your approach. Apply that style on the `tr` level instead of the `table` level
2. Use [removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove the class when clicked. **Or**, you can use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle the class when clicked.

```js
$(".tr_table").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('tr_table');
});
```

```css
.tg_table {
  width: 100%
}
.tr_table {
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr.tr_table {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg_table" border="1" style="">
  <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Neil</td>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>Ford</td>
    <td>98</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

> Unfortunately I cannot change the approach as the table is generated by php script

In that case, you can change the `tr` styles with [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

```js
$(".tr_table").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background', 'white');
  $(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```

```css
.tg_table {
  width: 100%
}
.tr_table {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg_table" border="1" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) !important;color:white !important;">
  <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Neil</td>
    <td>Mark</td> 
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="tr_table">
    <td>Mike</td>
    <td>Ford</td> 
    <td>98</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the approach as the table is generated by php script

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398279/remove-reset-inherited-css-from-an-element), you can't remove style that is inherited from parent unless you overwrite it. The best solution here, find a default style and when row clicked set this style which will remove the parent's style.

Code here, $(this) refers the clicked element.

```
$(".tr_table").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('style','background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;color:white !important;');
});
```